Bernoulis Equation and venturimeter
My Question is that in the following derivation for pressure in venturimeter ,we have done P1-P2=ρgh ,But why can't we apply bernoulis Equation at 1  and at the top of the tube above 1 where pressure is Patm  and for 2 respectively,On applying we get ρgh=0 but in the derivation we have done P2-P1 =ρgh ,which is valid for fluids at rest



Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead.

Who’s bernouli?

What we are really doing here is to find the velocity of the liquid in the Venturi meter. Now, it can be found using the Bernoulli Equation at the point at which we have to find the velocity.
This means that we have to apply Bernoulli Equation at the two points inside the tube and the pressures $P_1$ and $P_2$ are the pressures at the points at wide cross section and at narrow cross section respectively (inside the liquid).
So, $$P_2-P_1=\rho gh$$
Since, the height difference of water at the tubes fixed at the two cross sections is $h$.

You forget that Bernoulli only applies along streamlines, and the top of the tube is not on the same streamline as the $v_2$ flow. There is a surface of vortcity between them, and the Bernoulli constant jums across such surfaces.
